# Slow ulong bitwise AND in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, bitwise-and

I'm trying to optimize my chess program. I'm using `ulong` bitboards to generate legal moves as I thought it would be very quick. Profiler, however, suggests that much of the time is spent on bitwise AND operation (over 20% of inclusive samples, as shown below; analysis performed several times with the same result).

The profiled code was optimized x64, ran on VMWare Player (Windows 7 guest, Debian host). I couldn't get Mono Profiler to work to see if it produces the same results, but Mono executed natively on Linux ran code exactly the same time as .Net framework on VMWare.

Can the report shown below possibly be correct and the operation is indeed that heavy, am I misinterpreting it, or is the profiler inaccurate?

[image: Result of profiling]

Comment: Is `movesBitboard` a calculated property?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, it's a local variable defined in a line above the highlighted `filteredMovesBitboard` definition.

Comment: Ah, I see it now... The text in the image is hard to read.

Comment: I think the profiler may be a bit inaccurate. I think this is due to movesBitboard being evaluated when it is accessed. I could be wrong...

Comment: Is it faster compiled as x86?

Comment: @MichaelBaker No, it's almost the same (shows 21.4% on that suspicious line).

Comment: If you use a calculated value and a constant is it just as slow? Is this profiler like the VS exception helper that highlighs the wrong line when it encounters a throw statement? (highlights the line after throw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a profiler inaccuracy. I moved the line above the AND operation (`ulong movesBitboard = ...`) to some other location and now this line is marked as taking over 20% of samples - and that result is perfectly reasonable.